# How do I flip a sprite/texture in OpenGLES?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl

I have a sprite loaded as a texture and I need to animate it, allowing it to "face" left or right -- essentially sometimes I need to "flip" it.   I know that OpenGL has a gltranslate which repositions an object, and glrotate which rotates it.   Is there a method that simply flips it across one axis?  If not, how would you accomplish this?

Comment: You mean rotate it like a photo with a stuck to the middle, and rotating to the left and right? Or do you mean flip like a flip card?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't messed around with point sprites, but I believe that they are textures. Textures have texture matrices, which means you can use `glTranslatef()`, `glScalef()` and `glRotatef()` on them.

I would try out something along the lines of `glScalef(-1,1,1);` which would flip the texture coordinate by the X axis.

As I said, I haven't played with point sprites, but I didn't mess with texture matrices either. They do seem quite useful, though.

**Update:** I have played with texture matrices in the meantime. In the same way that you switch between modelview and projection matrices, you can switch to texture matrix; approximately: `glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);` after which you can do the aforementioned operations.

You could also just paint a quad/two triangles and be done with it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with OpenGL point-sprites; although you can move the center of the sprite around, the shape of it is always oriented the same way.

What you *can* do is draw your sprites as quads, which lets you flip, rotate and mess with them any way you want. There are tutorials on manually drawing sprites (aka billboards) on [NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/articles/article.asp?article=19)